# Calculation using Modulus

Tags: c

Currently working on an assignment that will ask the user for number of students, then calculate how many sections are required such that the fewest sections are required (each section has 35 students).

I'm stuck on figuring out how to use modulus to perform one of the calculations (we are supplied a sample run of the required program).

Here is what I have, I know it isn't much but even just a general idea would be helpful.

```
if (stdnt % std == 0) {
        sec = stdnt / std;

}
# of students  # of sections  standard section  last section 
 351             11              32               31
```

This is only part of the program.

**My problem:**

I can't figure out how to do the calculation so that if there is a remainder the section size shrinks to fit all the students in it.

*For Example*
User enters 350, there are 35 spots max per section, therefore there are 10 sections.  I can't figure out how to get 351 as shown in the table above.

Comment: So what is your problem, exactly?

Comment: If number of students doesn't divide evenly with number of students per section, then you need one more section for the remainder. `sec = stdnt / std; if (stdnt % std != 0) ++sec;`

Comment: a side note, if you are going to / and % in the same function, then save yourself some effort and use div. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/div/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are `MAX_PER_SECTION` (35 here) students per section maximally. Then, write

```
number_of_students = q * MAX_PER_SECTION + r
```

with `0 <= r < MAX_PER_SECTION`. If `r == 0`, then `q` sections are enough, otherwise we need `q+1`. You can obtain that number simply per

```
number_of_sections = (number_of_students - 1) / MAX_PER_SECTION + 1;
```

Now it remains to determine the best distribution of students among the sections, so that the difference between the number of students in the largest and the smallest sections is minimised. (You can always make that difference 0 or 1.) Again, use division with remainder to write

```
number_of_students = s * number_of_sections + t
```

with `0 <= t < number_of_sections`. Then we need `t` sections with `s+1` students, and the remaining `number_of_sections - t` sections will take `s` students.

In the example

```
351 = 10 * 35 + 1, number_of_sections = (351 - 1) / 35 + 1
```

so we need 11 sections, and

```
351 = 31 * 11 + 10,
```

hence we need 10 sections with 32 students and one section with 31.

Comment: what do r, q, s and t represent?  I don't understand.

Comment: `q` is the quotient of the division `number_of_students/MAX_PER_SECTION`, and `r` is the remainder of that division. Similarly for `s` and `t`. So `q <= number_of_students/MAX_PER_SECTION < q+1`, and we need either `q` or `q+1` sections to accommodate all students (depending on whether `r == 0` or not). And each section contains either `s = floor(number_of_students/number_of_sections)` students or `s+1`. How many sections must have `s+1` is what `t` tells us.

Comment: I don't understand what you said here:number_of_students = q * MAX_PER_SECTION + r with 0 <= r < MAX_PER_SECTION.   I don't understand what q and r are holding as a value.  I can initialize them to 0 but after that what is replacing that value?

Comment: `q = number_of_students / MAX_PER_SECTION` and `r = number_of_students % MAX_PER_SECTION`. Similar for `s` and `t`.

Comment: I figure that out, I still don't understand s and t though. lol.  here is what i have now  q = number_students / MAX_SEC;
 r = number_students % MAX_SEC;


 if (0 <= r < MAX_SEC) {
  number_sections = (number_students - 1) / MAX_SEC + 1;
 }

Comment: I'm still stuck on this. I can't get the Standard and Last sections to work right :(

Comment: `0 <= r < MAX_PER_SECTION` always holds (if `MAX_PER_SECTION > 0`), though if you take that as a C expression, it wouldn't do what you want (and might return false, if `MAX_PER_SECTION == 1`). I gave the correct formula for how many sections you need in the answer, the above is just the derivation. Then you get `min_students_per_section = number_of_students/number_of_sections;`. And then `number_of_large_sections = number_of_students % number_of_sections;` tells you how many sections with `min_students_per_section + 1` students you need.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo operation computes a remainder after division. Remember the formula

x = (x DIV n) + (x MOD n)

Where "x" and "n" are integers, "DIV" means whole number division and "MOD" means modulo operation. From that, you can get a C code:

```
int of_students       = 351;
int standard_section  = 35;

int last_section      = of_students % standard_section;
int of_sections       = of_students / standard_section;
if(last_section != 0) ++of_sections;
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well the modulus gives you the remainder, if the remainder is greater than zero you need another section for the remaining students. So for example taking your 351 students and dividing it by the number of students per section (35) will give you 10 sections, then using the modulus operator: 351%35 will return a remainder of 1 so you need an additional section to accommodate that one student.

Therefore psuedo code for the number of sections required is:

```
number_of_sections = 351/35
if( 351%1 > 0 ) number_of_sections += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int numOfSections = numOfStudent / sizeOfSection;
```

Basically this will give you the number of sections if there is no remainder then you want to make an if statement to check if there is a remainder. If so add 1 to numOfSection.

```
if(numOfStudent % sizeOfSection != 0)
   numOfSection++;
```